# How to get Bearer access token in Jmeter

Tags: authentication, curl, jmeter

I have problems to get Bearer access token in Jmeter. Problem's cause most probably is in
server authentication - do not really understand how to properly setup this in Jmeter.
curl consist of several parts:

> curl -X POST -v https://xxxx.xxx.xx.lv/token -u
> "d123c9e3-4e91-46db-931e-37e8a52b8c8d:0e7cb8ad50fe3686de05fcf46815abc0a9d7cd095c23f75446d933ccxyxy"
> -d "grant_type=password" -d "username=xxxxxxx" -d "password=xxxxxx" -d "scope=scop"

I have tried to use HTTP AuthorizationManager, HTTP Request and HTTP Header Manager without any successful results. Any advices?

Thanks!
Tatjana

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do something like:

1. [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler:

   [image]

these `protocol` and `Server Name` bits can be moved to [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) so you won't have to specify them for each and every HTTP Request sampler

2. [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager):

   [image]

---

In general [since JMeter 5.1 it's possible to create a test plan from curl command](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-5.1) line, the option lives under "Tools -> Import from cURL" main menu entry:

[image]